# How to complete a set of independent vectors to a basis of a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$\newcommand{\Span}{\operatorname{Span}}$Let $V$ be a vector such that $\dim V = n$, and let $v_1,\ldots,v_k \in V$ be independent vectors such that $1<k\leq n$. Now  Let $w_1,\ldots,w_r\in$ $\Span\left\{ v_1,\ldots,v_k \right\}$ be independent vectors such that $1\leq r <k$.

My question is this: How do I find the missing vectors $w_{r+1},\ldots,w_k\in \Span\left\{ v_1,\ldots,v_k \right\}$ so that $\Span\left\{w_1,\ldots,w_r,w_{r+1},\ldots,w_k\right\} = \Span\left\{ v_1,\ldots,v_k \right\}$ ?

Now I know they exist, I just don't know how I actually find them.

For example: Lets look at $\mathbb{R}^5$ and $$U=\Span\left\{  \begin{pmatrix} 5\\2\\3\\7\\3 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 2\\4\\4\\8\\1 \end{pmatrix} ,\begin{pmatrix} 3\\4\\7\\6\\1 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 5\\8\\6\\4\\8 \end{pmatrix} \right\}$$

Those are all independent vectors. Now lets take $2$ independent vectors that are linear combination of those. lets say, $$w_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 6\\2\\11\\15\\-3 \end{pmatrix} \; w_2=\begin{pmatrix} 0\\4\\-2\\12\\1 \end{pmatrix}$$ How can we complete those two vectors to form a basis of $U$ ?

I would really like to understand the general idea of this. This is actually a general question of something I need it for, which is the process of finding a Jordan basis for matrices\transformations.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1701880/expanding-a-linearly-independent-set-to-a-basis/1701904#1701904

Comment: Well its not quite the same as there he was looking for a completion for the whole space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one method for the case of $V = \Bbb R^n$: row-reduce the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{w_1 & \cdots & w_r & v_1 & \cdots & v_k}
$$
The columns of this matrix that eventually become *pivot columns* are precisely those which are linearly independent to the preceding columns.  It suffices, then, to take these columns to form your basis.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I don't think I quite understand what you meant here, but here is the the row-reduced matrix of $\begin{pmatrix}w_{1} & w_{2} & v_{1} & v_{2} & v_{3} & v_{4}\end{pmatrix}$ as in the example: $$\begin{pmatrix}1 &  &  &  & 0 & -1\\
 & 1 &  &  & -\frac{1}{2} & -1\\
 &  & 1 &  & 0 & 1\\
 &  &  & 1 & \frac{3}{2} & 3\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$How should I go on ?

Comment: @Jon in the row-reduced matrix, the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and 4th columns have pivots (leading $1$s).  Correspondingly, we take the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and 4th columns of the original matrix to make our basis.  That is, the set $\{w_1,w_2,v_1,v_2\}$ is a basis of $V$.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much =)

Answer (score 0):

Write $w_1,w_2$ as a linear combination of $\mathcal{B} = (v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)$ and put the coefficients as the first two columns of a $4 \times 4$ matrix:

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} [w_1]_{\mathcal{B}} & [w_2]_{\mathcal{B}} &  ? & ?  \end{pmatrix}. $$

Fill the third and fourth columns of $A$ in any way you want as long as the resulting matrix will be invertible (you can check it with the determinant or in many other ways - the most comfortable way will depend on the specific form of $A$ you get). Then define $w_3$ as a linear combination of the $v_i$ using the third column and similarly for $w_4$. This guarantess that $(w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4)$ will form a basis of $U = \operatorname{span} \mathcal{B}$ and any basis of $U$ in which the first two elements are $w_1,w_2$ is obtained in this way.

This also generalizes in the obvious way to the case $r < k \leq n$.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. Well I guess that returns me to the same question. How would I fill those 3rd and 4th columns in such a way that A would be invertible?

Comment: @Jon: Well, that depends on the first two columns. For example, if the upper-left $2 \times 2$ matrix is invertible, you can put zeros in the upper-right $2 \times 2$ matrix and $I_2$ in the lower-right $2 \times 2$ matrix. Then you'll get a lower-triangular matrix which must be invertible. If not, you'll need to play with it some more. Also, any "random" choice will work (with probability $1$). The point is that in any homework question like this I've ever seen in which the students were expected to solve the problem without using a computer, it was possible to complete the columns by

Comment: applying heuristics like the one I described. If you want an algorithm that always works (for example, if you want to write a code that does it), then it is better to take the row/column reduction approach.

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean. Its true that eventually the matrices we get are at most 5x5, but also I wanted to look for an algorithm as you mentioned which could help me with that. How could I use the row/column reduction approach?

Answer (score 0):

If I have correctly understood the question: you choose a vector of $v_i  \in Span\{v_1, ..., v_k\}$, check if it is linearly independent from $w_1$ and $w_2$, then solve the system $ \alpha w_1 + \beta w_2 + \gamma x = v_i $, where $x = (x_1, ..., x_n)$ is your new vector in $Span\{w_1,...,w_k\}$. Now, repeat.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was looking for a more effective way than just choosing random vectors from Span$\left\{ v_1,\ldots,v_k \right\}$ and hoping they would be independent  with $w_1,w_2$.

Comment: @Jon you can find what $e_i = (0, ...1_i, ..., 0) \in Span\{v_1,...,v_k\}$, so you can choose with less difficult a vector probably indipendent from $w_1$ and $w_2$, but I don't remember now a way without a random choice.

Comment: So let me see if I have understood you right. First you suggest that ill check which of $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ belongs to Span$\left\{ v_1,\ldots,v_k \right\}$, and after that I should check which one of them is not dependent  on $w_1,\ldots,w_r$ ?

Comment: @Jon Yes, the vectors with more zeros are easier to use, but you still have to choise the best $e_i \in Span\{V\}$ "randomly", without a technique to know if it will be independent on $w_1$ and $w_2$